# Laravel Valet not serving style.css file

Tags: css, laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

I am currently switching to Laravel Valet as a simple webserver and am serving my current project under `project.test`. Everything - including PHP,  JS and CSS - is serving file except my `assets/css/style.css` file.

When I open it in the browser I get an empty result and a 200 response code. When I rename the file to `assets/css/main.css` it is serving fine - only with the file name `style.css`. I also tried clearing my browser cache, using another browser, ensuring Valet has enough permissions to read the file (the file has the same permissions as the other files that are served successfully) and completely restarting Laravel Valet but it won't serve the file.

Do you have any idea why it won't serve my `assets/css/style.css` file?

Comment: Can you please share your laravel mix configuration?

Comment: assets is a folder under the public directory or in the resources?

Comment: @VictorH.Avelar and @nakov The project I am hosting is not a Laravel project but a simple SlimPHP project with only an `index.php` file and my other assets in the `assets` folder. The file `assets/css/style.css` is in that directory in my filesystem, there is no Laravel router inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

[Can you ls -la /Library/LaunchDaemons and see if there is a Laravel/Valet looking file in there? If so, delete it :)](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/323#issuecomment-299469895)

Maybe this can solve your issue ?

Comment: It seems like there are no Laravel/Valet looking files there.